# What is connected in class diagrams

Tags: java, class-diagram

I would like to create a class diagram for my java project. Even if this sounds very simple, I am just a bit confused now.

I am familiar with the symbolic but when do I have to create a connection between two classes?

For example I have a StartClass:

```
Model model = new Model();
View view = new View();
Controller controller = new Controller(view, model);
```

It is clear that `StartClass` is connected with `Model`, `View` and `Controller`. But is `Controller` now also connected with `Model` and `View`?

Or another example:

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
ClassB classB = new ClassB();

classB.methodB(classA);
```

Does `ClassB` and `ClassA` have now a connection between each other?

Sorry for this really simple question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Controller looks like the following, then it has a connection to Model and View.

```
class Controller {
   public Controller(View view, Model model) {
       this.view = view;
       this.model = model;
   }
}
```

Or more generally: any class reference saved in a member variable inside a class will be a connection in a class diagram.

Comment: It doesn't have to be stored in a member variable to be connected. For example, a class that performs a manipulation on objects of a certain class without keeping track of the manipulated objects does have a connection to that other class (of course, that functionality could then be implemented in the other class as it doesn't depend on the first one [barring such cases where allowing the first class to handle the manipulation is more generalized, generally when interfaces come into play], but that's a different issue).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a couple years since I've had to fuss around with UML diagrams, but Wikipedia seems to have a good explanation of the usual relationships (association, aggregation, composition, generalization [class inheritance], realization [interface implementation]).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Relationships

In the case of `classB.methodB(classA);`, I believe that would be considered general association, as it's one object performing an action on/with another (if `methodB()` does something to store `classA` in `classB`, it would be aggregation specifically, or possibly even composition if `classB` will hold on to `classA` for the rest of the program).

Answer (score 1):

Here in you first example, you are creating different objects of classes: Model,View and Controller.So as you saying class is connected with Model,View and Controller and also controller is connected with Model and View.

Same in second example, both classes: Class A and Class B has a new connection between each other.

Answer (score 0):

When you get into the MVC pattern things get a little trickier, but MSDN has a good explanation of how to model those relationships: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx

In general however, when it comes to modeling your application, you would only connect those classes that are declared as members of another class, not all that are used within the class in some capacity (would you add the string or int class just because you use it as a parameter of a method?).